# Find the second top selling product in terms of sales and quantity

Tags: sql, window-functions

There are two Tables - **orders** and **item_line**

**orders**

| order_id | created_at | total_amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-11-11 13:40:50 | 450.00 |
| 124 | 2022-10-30 00:40:50 | 1500.00 |

**item_line**

| order_id | product_id | product_name | quantity | unit_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | a1b | milo | 4 | 100.00 |
| 123 | c2d | coke | 5 | 10.00 |
| 124 | c2d | coke | 150 | 10.00 |

**The question is:**
Find the **second top selling** product in terms of sales and quantity in the current year sold between 6PM to 9PM.

My Take on This is -

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT i.product_name,
            SUM(o.total_amount)sales,
            SUM(i.quantity)total_qty,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(o.total_amount) DESC,SUM(i.quantity)total_qty DESC) AS rn
    FROM item_line i
    WHERE o.created_at BETWEEN 18:00:00 AND 21:00:00
    JOIN orders o on o.order_id = i.order_id
    GROUP BY i.product_name ) temp
WHERE rn = 2;
```

But it's not correct. What wrong I am doing?

Comment: You have many issues - for a start you should review basic query syntax and understand the order of `from/join/where`; your analytic function syntax has issues, your scalar time values should be delmited and more.

Comment: "in terms of sales and quantity", you are summing up total cost from orders where items contributing to that cost are mixed unless that is the intention. Sales might perhaps be `q_sold * quantity`. And check your syntax as already mentioned in one of the comments.

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM ( 
 SELECT i.product_name,SUM(o.total_amount)AS 'Net Sales',
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(o.total_amount) DESC) AS rn
 FROM item_line i
 JOIN orders o on o.order_id = i.order_id
 GROUP BY i.product_name) temp
WHERE rn =2;```    I have corrected it and getting the answers as well, but sill stuck with the time criterion.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT i.product_name,SUM(o.total_amount)AS 'Net Sales',
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(o.total_amount) DESC) AS rn
    FROM item_line i
    JOIN orders o on o.order_id = i.order_id
    WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,o.created_at) BETWEEN 18 AND 21
    GROUP BY i.product_name) temp
WHERE rn =2;

        -- In terms of total quantity
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT i.product_name,SUM(i.quantity)AS 'Total Quantity',
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(i.quantity) DESC) AS rn
    FROM item_line i
    JOIN orders o on o.order_id = i.order_id
    WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,o.created_at) BETWEEN 18 AND 21
    GROUP BY i.product_name) temp
WHERE rn =2;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
select o.order_id, sum(quantity), total_amount from orders [o] 
inner join item_line[i] on o.order_id = i.order_id
group by o.order_id, total_amount order by total_amount desc, sum(quantity) desc

OFFSET     1 ROWS       
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

you can add target date time in filter

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).